# Figure numbers according to sections and subsections

Tags: latex

I want to generate the figure numbers depending on the sections, for example, if section number is 1.1 then I want to generate the figure numbers as 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is better asked on the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 16):

Add

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

to your preamble.

Reference:

- [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/5764)

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{figure}}
```

to your document. This will redefine the figure number to contain the section and subsection number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{subtitle}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{content...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to add a little more detail to your answer. Also, wrap code with grave marks (`).

Comment: Try to Add some description with your code. What your code doing ? How it solving the problem ?